# Video card driver causing Windows Vista to blue screen

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, windows-vista, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I bought an HP Pavilion dv2000 back when Windows Vista first came out and it was working quite well until the video card drivers started acting up 6 months ago.  The laptop has an nVidia GeForce Go7200 and would blue-screen-of-death for the folliwng reason:

nvlddmkm.sys

The blue-screen-of-death would occur randomly while running Windows Vista.  No particular application would cause the issue.  Then it started occurring during boot up.  The only way I could run my laptop was in safe mode.

There was a driver update available through Windows update.  I installed the update and it did not resolve the issue.

I reinstalled Vista on my laptop and it still kept happening.  I have uninstalled the drivers and it is working with the default Vista video drivers.

Has anyone ever experienced this issue and know how to fix it?

Comment: Did installing the new drivers as Troggy suggested help?

Comment: @Nathan - Yes, I have reinstalled the drivers a few times and it did not solve the issue.  I am sending in my laptop to HP for service.  Hopefully that will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent in my HP pavilion dv2000 in Hewlett Packard for service and they have informed me that I have a bad motherboard and processor.  They offered me the option to replace the each item for a total cost of $733 US dollars.  I declined and told them not to the original repairs on the notebook, so I am only out the initial $50 to speak with HP technical support.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the drivers that came with the machine or off the manuafactor website, you might want to try the driver from nvidia's website.

32bit http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_notebook_winvista_179.48_beta.html

64bit http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_notebook_winvista64_179.48_beta.html