# I have a dead laptop, what are my options?

Tags: laptop-repair

After having my previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/16636/video-card-driver-causing-windows-vista-to-blue-screen) answered by the HP technical support, I now have a HP laptop that does not work properly.  HP recommended that I replace the motherboard and processor for a bargain price of $733 US dollars.

I originally purchased this laptop back when the Windows Vista was released back in January 2007 for about $2,000 US dollar, but now is an very expensive paperweight.

What are my options for this laptop?  Do I try to revive it on my own....

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://laptoprescuer.com/ worked for me, I think you will get a better price buying the service through ebay, they are in Santa Clara, California, near the San Jose airport. The will do component level repair, they fixed a laptop of mine that another shop had said needed a new MB. Fixed or you don't pay.

Comment: @Ronald - I will give these guys a try.  It will only cost me shipping to get the computer to CA.  I am already $50 in the hole just making a phone call to HP, plus they want over $1000 to replace the motherboard, processor and graphics card.....what a rip off!

Comment: I heard back from laptop rescuer last week and they going to replace the video card chip for $260 US dollars.  I should get back by next week.  Thank your for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly try a fresh install of the operating system.   I might suggest a trial version of Windows 7 as it seems to have better driver support [Windowes 7 Enterprise Trial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx?ITPID=sprblog).  I have had techs report failed main boards and other hardware as it is sometimes an easy way to resolve an issue.  Easy for them, not so much for you.  I had an older Compaq system that needed a new mother board but worked great after a fresh install. Recently Dell replaced RAM, Processor and Main board under warranty but we were finally able to determinethe issue was a bad Firewire card. At least worth a try as your system is realtively new.

Comment: I reinstalled Vista multiple times and it did not resolve the issue.  I still was experiencing video card/driver issues.

Comment: Understood.  Personally found Windows 7 handled this better on systems I have worked on.  Especially video drivers. Just thinking cost is your time to download and run the install as opposed to $$$

Comment: I will go ahead and give Windows 7 a try.  Let you know the results.

Comment: I just installed Windows 7 and it is demonstrating the same symptoms as before...I think I just might have some bad hardware...ugh!

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that the motherboard, card and processor are not to blame...look for excessive heat. I remember reading articles about nvidia chipsets & hp laptops having heat issues but I can't find them anymore (just articles on battery recalls)...still it's worth a shot.

Other options: Give a Linux distro a try. The nv and nouveau drivers will access your hardware somewhat differently than the binary only nvidia driver (which will behave similarly to the Windows one) so give them all a test if you can.